# MQTT Mosquitto - Persistence file won't autosave(update) after reached the time interval

Tags: persistence, mqtt, mosquitto

I have set the time interval for autosave to 30 seconds but the broker won't auto update the persistence file even though it reached the time interval.

This are my settings:

```
autosave_interval 30
autosave_on_changes true
persistence true
persistence_file mosquitto.db
persistence_location C:\mosquitto\persistence\
```

I have to manually close the broker in order get the persistence file updated. Is there any other option I need to turned on? or is there any condition?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does `c:\mosquitto\persistence` already exists and if so does the user to the broker have permission to write to it?

Comment: hi, i already figure out why. It is the quote in between the persistence location that make the argument invalid. I have updated my question, it is about the broker wont auto update the persistence file after reached the time interval.

Comment: The file is only of any use if the broker is restarted or crashes to restore the state of remote clients with queued messages or persistent subscriptions, it is of NO other use. It will update only when the timeout happens if there is a chance that needs recording.

Comment: So normal publishing and subscribing is not part of the data that will recorded into the file? Only those with cleasnsession set to false and have QOS 1 or 2 will be recorded(if the client disconnected), am I right?

Comment: A messages will only be stored in the persistence file if the broker has failed to deliver it to a client for some reason (e.g. for a client without a clean session and is currently off line) or while the handshaking for a QOS1/2 message is still going on. Once the handshake for a QOS1/2 message is complete the message will be totally discarded.

Comment: Even if a message is stored in the file, there is no way to get at it, as the only code that exists to read the file is in the broker, so of no use to a end user.

Comment: Ok. That's clarify my questions. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but

> If autosave_on_changes is enabled, the autosave_interval is
> interpreted as changes in retained, received and queued messages
> instead of seconds. The default database file name can be changed with
> persistence_file.

What I understand from this is, since your `autosave_on_changes` is set to true, it'll only save when you have 30 messages queued.